# How do i link my smart contract and my UI? Tested my smart contract in buidl http://buidl.secondstate.io/. I am trying to use Parastate for this

Tags: solidity

```
contract BasicContract {
  int s_amount;
  address s_owner;
  constructor() public {
  s_owner = msg.sender;
  s_amount = 0;
}
modifier onlyOwner() {
  require(msg.sender == s_owner);
  _;
}
function deposit(int v) public   {
  require(v >= 0);
  s_amount = s_amount + v;
}
function withdraw(int v) public onlyOwner { require(v >= 0);
  require(s_amount >= v);
  s_amount = s_amount - v;
}

function getBalance() constant public returns (int retVal) { 
  return s_amount;
}
function getAddress() constant public returns (address a) { 
  return s_owner;
}
}
```

This is my solidity contract. This was successfully compiled and tested.
Now I need to connect this to a web UI

Answer (score 0):

Load [BUIDL for ParaState](http://buidl.secondstate.io/?s042&web3_provider=https%3A%2F%2Frpc.parastate.io%3A8545&web3_chainId=123&gas_price=1&gas_limit=8000000)

Click to open Account, select Import, import the MetaMask private key just set up into the BUIDL account

Copy your contract and run.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through http://buidl.secondstate.io/ , click dApp and you will see your frontend project.(with "html" "css" and "js" buttons to navigate)

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://buidl.secondstate.io/. Find the dApp tab there. You can build a web interface fr your dApp there, test and publish it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

1. Follow the link http://buidl.secondstate.io/
2. Click dApp
3. Review your frontend project.

Answer (score 0):

go http://buidl.secondstate.io/ and choose dapp,then code,test and publish

Answer (score -1):

you can check dapp section at http://buidl.secondstate.io/.

Comment: Please don't post solo links as answers.